# Interleave two branches into linear history

Tags: git, branch

I have two branches `a` and `b` on top of a `main` branch, where each branch has commits at different points in time.

For example:

```
                c5 ---- c7   <-- a
               /
c1 -- c2 -- c3               <-- main
             \
             c4 ---- c6      <-- b
```

I'd like to interleave the commits from `a` and `b` according to their author date into a linear history and fast-forward `main`.

```
c1 -- c2 -- c3 -- c4 -- c5 -- c6 -- c7     <-- main
```

Is there a better way to achieve this than manually cherry-picking the commits from `a` and `b` onto `main`?

Comment: Rebase one on top of the other then do an interactive rebase on top of master so that you get the full list of commits and you can reorder them nicely there.... not automagic, but no cherry-picking on your part involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, list them in author-date order and cherry-pick the list.

```
git checkout main
git rev-list --reverse --author-date-order a...b | git cherry-pick --stdin
```

. . . I see the `--stdin` option is all but undocumented, it's used in an example on the manpage, that's a pretty clear doc bug.

---

The three-dot syntax `a...b` [is convenience shorthand for `a b --not $(git merge-base --all a b)`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#Documentation/gitrevisions.txt-Theememthree-dotSymmetricDifferenceNotation). To extend it to more branches you need to use the full spelling and extend that, `a b c --not $(git merge-base --all a b c)`.

Comment: Thanks! Is there an easy way to generalize this from using two branches to more branches?